# 2-gram of two consecutive letters python

Tags: python

A so-called 2-gram is defined as a block of two consecutive letters. For instance, in the sequence AACTGC we can find five different 2-grams: AA, AC, CT, TG and GC (notice that two consecutive 2-grams overlap in one letter). It is easy to see that in a sequence of    letters, we can count  −1  2-grams (many of them may be repeated, so the total number of different 2-grams is possibly smaller).

For sequences composed by letters whose alphabet is of size 4 (like the virus RNA, whose alphabet is made by four letters A,C,G and T), there are a total of  24=16  possible 2-grams: AA,AC,AG,AT,...,TT.

By modifying the function freq() (or otherwise), compute and plot a histogram (bar graph plot) of the frequency of 2-grams in the virus sequence. The x axis should depict all sixteen combinations of the four nucleotides.

Comment: I need a function that takes in the virus sequence ( For example 'AATCGGTAATTCCA') , finds the different 2-grams and counts how many times each pair of 2-grams occur and plot a frequency histogram

Comment: Also the only modules I can use are Matplotlib, numpy, pandas, seaborn

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this is what you want to do:

```
gram = "ACTG"
two_gram = dict()
for letter1 in gram:
    for letter2 in gram:
        two_gram[letter1+letter2] = 0
print(two_gram)
virus_ARN = "AATGCAACGATGCAAACATGGAGC"
for a,b in zip(virus_ARN[0:-1],virus_ARN[1:]):
    two_gram[a+b] = two_gram[a+b]+1
print(two_gram)
```

Just plot the histogram based on `two_gram`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, try to adapt to your problem.

```
text='AACTGC'
import re

def gram_2(text):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(1,len(text)):
        p=text[i-1:i+1]

        p=re.findall('\w{2}',p)
        lst=[*lst,*p]
    return len(lst),lst

print(gram_2(text))
# (5, ['AA', 'AC', 'CT', 'TG', 'GC'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of counting 2grams and their counts from a sequence.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> prod = list(map(''.join, product(['A', 'C', 'T', 'G'], repeat=2)))
>>> ngrams = dict.fromkeys(prod, 0)

>>> seq = 'AATGAATTGCCTGATAAAAAGGATTACCTTGATAGGGTAAATCATGCAGTTTTCTGCATTCATTGACTGATTTATATATT'
>>> for i in range(len(seq)-1):
    ngram = seq[i:i+2]
    ngrams[ngram] += 1

>>> from pprint import pprint   
>>> pprint(ngrams)
{'AA': 8,
 'AC': 2,
 'AG': 3,
 'AT': 13,
 'CA': 4,
 'CC': 2,
 'CG': 0,
 'CT': 4,
 'GA': 6,
 'GC': 3,
 'GG': 3,
 'GT': 2,
 'TA': 7,
 'TC': 3,
 'TG': 8,
 'TT': 11}
```

For the bar chart, you might want to use [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dmatplotlib.pyplot+bar+chart)

Answer (score 0):

Do You want this? ->

```
s = 'AACTGC'
result = set(map(''.join,zip(s,(s[-1] + s[1:]))))
```

If you want tokeep the order ->

```
# pip install ordered_set
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
s = 'AACTGC'
result = set(map(''.join,zip(s,(s[-1] + s[1:]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a simple (pythonic) approach to solve the question:

```
import random
from itertools import product

letters = 'ACGT'
twograms = [f"{a}{b}" for a, b in product(letters, letters)]
# Next line only required to generate fake input sequence
mystring = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(200))
bins = {tg: mystring.count(tg) for tg in twograms}
print(bins)
```

returns:

```
{'AA': 10,
 'AC': 15,
 'AG': 11,
 'AT': 14,
 'CA': 11,
 'CC': 10,
 'CG': 14,
 'CT': 12,
 'GA': 13,
 'GC': 13,
 'GG': 7,
 'GT': 12,
 'TA': 16,
 'TC': 10,
 'TG': 13,
 'TT': 12}
```

Comment: I too considered using [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) but realized, from the docs, that it only counts non-overlapping occurrences. His problem counts overlapping sequences.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks a lot for sharing